# Makefile for OpenGL with glad on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl

I want to use **glad** in my OpenGL project but I am not quite sure how to create the Makefile for it. I downladed glad from the webservice and moved the directories from include/ (glad/ and KHR/) to /usr/include/ (Now emacs sees the library) and the glad.c file to the root of my project (which at the moment contatns only a demo source.cpp file).

I have this Makefile:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Linux)
    COMPILER = g++
    FLAGS = -std=c++1y -pedantic -Wall
    GL_FLAGS = -lGL -lglfw
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
    COMPILER = clang++
    FLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -pedantic -Wall
    GL_FLAGS = -lGLEW -framework OpenGL -lm
endif
FILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
APP_NAME = opengl-app

all: main

main: $(FILES)
    $(COMPILER) $(FLAGS) $(FILES) glad.c -o $(APP_NAME) $(GL_FLAGS)

.PHONY: clean run
clean:
    rm opengl-app

run: opengl-app
    ./opengl-app
```

This when executed gives these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc0DUjDZ.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help with the makefile will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a linker error, seems unrelated to `make`. You probably forgot to add some library.

Comment: `glad` makes use of `dlopen`/`dlclose` so you need to link with `libdl.so`.  Add `-ldl` to your linker flags.

Comment: The -ldl fixed it thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @G.M. `glad` makes use of `dlopen/dlclose`, methods used to load shared objects in Linux.

The Makefile should add the link flag to use `libdl.so`. The final result should be something like this:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Linux)
    COMPILER = g++
    FLAGS = -std=c++1y -pedantic -Wall
    GL_FLAGS = -lGL -lglfw
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
    COMPILER = clang++
    FLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -pedantic -Wall
    GL_FLAGS = -lGLEW -framework OpenGL -lm
    GLAD_FLAGS = -ldl
endif
FILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
APP_NAME = opengl-app

all: main

main: $(FILES)
    $(COMPILER) $(FLAGS) $(FILES) glad.c -o $(APP_NAME) $(GL_FLAGS) $(GLAD_FLAGS)

.PHONY: clean run
clean:
    rm opengl-app

run: opengl-app
    ./opengl-app
```